# How can I use Python with PowerDesigner?

Tags: python-3.x, powerdesigner

I want to run a PDM or a XML file to PowerDesigner using Python code. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it and please guide me or help with links to follow.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific module.

But [it looks like](https://pbpython.com/windows-com.html) you can use a module like pywin32 to access PowerDesigner Automation API.

Comment: sounds interesting, is there any documention on using it with python to access powerdesigner?